# Array of **NSObject** Contains Any Element of other array of **NSObject**

Tags: ios, arrays

it looks silly question but i have big doubt how to check that without for loop efficiently  check that

i have array of NSObject class contains 3 element say Array1

```
<__NSArrayI 0x7fb6952437b0>(
   <ActiveBidModel: 0x7fb6950f0680>,
   <ActiveBidModel: 0x7fb69516d500>,
   <ActiveBidModel: 0x7fb69514f190>
)
```

And on Other hand i have other array contains Same 3 Elements but with different memory address and different sorting order  Say Array2

```
 <__NSArrayM 0x7fb695208ac0>(
 <ActiveBidModel: 0x7fb6952226e0>,
 <ActiveBidModel: 0x7fb69515f730>,
 <ActiveBidModel: 0x7fb695145cb0>
 )
```

Now i want check if Element that are in Array1 contains Any of element of Array2 or both array are equal

i have try with == operator , isEqual, isEqualToArray but no luck 
also try with NSSet intersect

---

### Edit

if i compare Array1[0] == Array2[2] // suppose i know index of both equal element then it returns **true**

Comment: What does equality actually mean for two `ActiveBidModel` objects?  (When you say "Same 3 Elements but with different memory address", it doesn't make sense for `NSObject`'s standard definition.)

Comment: mean all values in  `ActiveBidModel` is same with other model @PhillipMills

Comment: i know that i can do that , that's why i post it to find better solution  other than looping and compare each @Mrunal

Comment: can you replace arrays with dictionaries ?

Comment: @sage444 not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object` for `ActiveBidModel` so that it returns `YES` when the internal values match.

Then, the arrays will report equal if all of the contents are equal and in the same order.

To handle different ordering, convert to sets.

For example, a named "MyObject" has:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
    BOOL result = NO;
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[MyObject class]]) {
        result = [self.name isEqualToString:[object name]];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Test cases:

```
NSArray *a1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[MyObject alloc] initWithName:@"name"], [[MyObject alloc] initWithName:@"name2"], nil];
NSArray *a2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[MyObject alloc] initWithName:@"name2"], [[MyObject alloc] initWithName:@"name"], nil];
if ([a1 isEqual:a2]) {
    NSLog(@"Array match");
} else {
    NSLog(@"No array match");
}
NSSet *s1 = [NSSet setWithArray:a1];
NSSet *s2 = [NSSet setWithArray:a2];
if ([s1 isEqual:s2]) {
    NSLog(@"Set match");
} else {
    NSLog(@"No set match");
}
```

> 2016-09-01 10:29:27.818 Collection[28481:1193715] No array match
>
> 2016-09-01 10:29:32.330 Collection[28481:1193715] Set match

Comment: Thanks for your answer , it is working but i noticed that `- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object` method is called on `NSSet *s1 = [NSSet setWithArray:a1];` for each object and also called for if condition , i am not understanding why it is calling on creating set

Comment: I'm guessing, but....  Since sets don't store duplicate objects, the set initialization probably needs to test whether objects being added are unique.